# ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/npm'

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps, azure-devops

I'm trying to deploy an app to azure App Service and I'm running in this issue:

```
Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'closur-test'
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id '1fcc5bf589'.
Generating deployment script.
Using the following command to generate deployment script: 'azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment -r "/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted" -o "/home/site/deployments/tools" --basic --sitePath "/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted"'.
Generating deployment script for Web Site
Generated deployment script files
Running deployment command...
Command: "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
Handling Basic Web Site deployment.
Kudu sync from: '/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted' to: '/home/site/wwwroot'
Copying file: '.babelrc'
Copying file: '.gitignore'
Copying file: '.sequelizerc'
Copying file: 'azure-pipelines.yml'
Copying file: 'nodemon.json'
Copying file: 'package-lock.json'
Copying file: 'package.json'
Copying file: 'tsconfig.json'
Copying file: 'tslint.json'
Ignoring: .git
Copying file: '.vscode/extensions.json'
Copying file: '.vscode/launch.json'
Copying file: '.vscode/settings.json'
Copying file: '.vscode/tasks.json'
Copying file: 'dist/index.js'
Copying file: 'dist/index.js.map'
Copying file: 'dist/db/Models/index.js'
Copying file: 'dist/db/Models/index.js.map'
Copying file: 'dist/db/config/config.js'
Copying file: 'dist/db/config/config.js.map'
Copying file: 'dist/web/routes/user.js'
Copying file: 'dist/web/routes/user.js.map'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/npm'
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Kudu Sync failed
\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
App container will begin restart within 10 seconds.
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
Successfully updated deployment History at https://closur-test.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/501560405080357
App Service Application URL: http://closur-test.azurewebsites.net
##[section]Finishing: deploy to app service: clos
```

ur-test

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having something similar happen